# How to run two elixir tasks in sequence?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, laravel-elixir

Take a look at this code:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir')
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('t1', function() {
  return gulp.src('1/1.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('2'));
});

gulp.task('t2', function() {
  // setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(fs.existsSync('2/1.js'));
  // }, 100);
  return gulp.src('2/1.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('3'));
});

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.task('t1').task('t2');
});
```

When I uncomment `setTimeout`, `console.log` starts outputting `true`. Which supposedly means, that second task start when the first one hasn't finished. Is there a way to make them run one after another?

What I'm really trying to do is to `browserify` my js files, append some other files to them (custom task) and `version` the result. But versioning fails, because the file isn't there yet.

P.S. Before running `gulp` do `mkdir 1 && touch 1/1.js`. And do `rm {2,3}/1.js` before each run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The issue](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/380) here is that `laravel-elixir` wraps this sort of tasks in ones generated dynamically. The wrappers are executed in sequence. But they appear to not wait until the subtasks are finished.

So, the best I could come up with is this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var fs = require('fs');

elixir.extend('inlineTask', function(func, watcher) {
  var task = new elixir.Task(func.name, func);
  if (watcher) {
    task.watch(watcher);
  }
});

elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.inlineTask(function t1() {
    console.log('1 -> 2');
    return gulp.src('1/1.js')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('2'));
  }, '1/**/*.js').inlineTask(function t2() {
    console.log('2 -> 3');
    console.log(fs.existsSync('2/1.js'));
    return gulp.src('2/1.js')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('3'));
  }, '2/**/*.js');
});
```